# java vector scoping

Tags: java

I am trying to make use of a class variable (vector) and get the following 2 errors

1

> ```
> <identifier> expected
> [javac]     bucketList = AppConfig.findVector (BUCKET_LIST_KEY);
> ```

2
    in the `getBucketList()` method, `bucketList` is null for some reason... even though its defined as a global variable for the class.

CODE

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class MyClass {
   ...
   private Vector<String> bucketList;

   public ThingieConfig() throws IOException {

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     bucketList = AppConfig.findVector (BUCKET_LIST_KEY);       
     if (bucketList != null && !bucketList.isEmpty()) {
       log_.debug ("Bucketlist defined");
       log_.debug("Buckets Defined : " + bucketList);
     }//if
   }//thingie

   public Vector getBucketList() {
    log_.debug ("Returning Vector " + bucketList);
    return bucketList;
    }//getBucketList

}//class
```

Comment: not enough information to answer this.  What is BUCKET_LIST_KEY and what is findVector?  Further `public ThingieConfig()` is not a valid function declaration.  you need an `Object` or `void` as a return type

Answer (score 1):

Defining it member variable of class doesn't mean it will have that default initialization, By default it would be `null`

method declaration needs return type, and following is invalid

```
public ThingieConfig() throws IOException
```

Comment: thanks for help... but how do i fix this: bucketList = AppConfig.findVector (BUCKET_LIST_KEY);

Answer (score 1):

```
public ThingieConfig()
```

is not a valid method. There is no return type for it but the class name is `MyClass` so it cannot be the constructor.

Comment: thanks for help... but how do i fix <identifier> expected error

Comment: are you still getting the error after you fix that? if so, can you post the line number and corresponding line numbers from your code?

Answer (score 1):

bucketList needs to be initialized:

```
 private Vector<String> bucketList = new Vector<String>();
```

you need to state what your method returns, or void:

```
public void ThingieConfig() throws IOException {
```

Comment: java:97: <identifier> expected

Comment: bucketList = AppConfig.findVector (BUCKET_LIST_KEY);

Comment: Commenting with line numbers doesn't really help when you didn't include them in your original source code. getBucketList() will return null if ThingieConfig() has not already been run. Can you please type full sentences to tell me if you have any further problems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `bucketList = AppConfig.findVector (BUCKET_LIST_KEY);` is valid once all other errors are fixed, here is what I did to fix it.

Somewhere, the `bucketList` needs to be initialized.
For example, in the first line of `ThingieConfig()`, you could put
`bucketList = new Vector<String>();`. This may not be the best location for you, but it should appear somewhere.

Also, every method needs a return type. So the line

`public ThingieConfig() throws IOException {`

should be

`public Vector<String> ThingieConfig() throws IOException {`

(since you return your bucketList).

Lastly, `Vector` is deprecated in Java. I would consider using `ArrayList` instead.